# How can I automatically enable a VSIX extension, when installing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I've created a VSIX package that I install via a WIX-generated MSI.

However, when I install it, and look at it in VS2010, in the **Tools > Extension Manager** menu, it is **[Disabled]** and I need to enable it manually.

How can I avoid this?

** EDIT **
Here's what I did:
I tried adding capturing the VSInstallDir from the registry like this:

```
    <Property Id="VSINSTALLER">
  <RegistrySearch Id="VSInstallRegistry" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0" Name="InstallDir"  Type="directory" />
```

I added the directory structure under target-dir like this:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="VSINSTALLER">
    <Directory Id="Extensions" Name="Extensions">
      <Directory Id="Copy_CompanyFolder" Name="my company">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLVSIX" Name="app name">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

And I added a CopyFile element to the component in the installation folder, like this:

```
            <Component Id="VsPackage" Guid="00000000-0000-some-guid-00000000">
          <File Id="VsPackageInstaller" Source="$(folder.prop)\extensionName.vsix"
                KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1">
            <CopyFile Id="Copy_InstallVsix"
                      DestinationDirectory="INSTALLVSIX" />
          </File>
        </Component>
```

And I added the **true** element to the manifest.

When I do this, the extension is **not** installed.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. Definitely don't do it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install your extension files to a directory you create under %VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\Extensions, it will be enabled automatically for all users. This is the recommendation for MSI-installed extensions.

Also, please be sure to add `<InstalledByMsi>true</InstalledByMsi>` to your vsixmanifest.

There is no need to run VSIXInstaller.exe or write registry keys to enable your extension (In fact, you really shouldn't do this.).

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. How do you add the VSIX file? See edit for what I did.

Comment: In the case I suggest, you need to lay down your *loose files* on disk, not the '.vsix' file. (i.e. your extension.vsixmanifest from the project output folder, DLL's, Pkgdef files, etc...)

Comment: If the extension is installed by .MSI but not in the Common7 folder, what's the recommendation to enable it at install? The Extension Manager UI is all grayed out so the end-user cannot enable it himself (which I find stupid).

Comment: @Simon Have you found out the trick to enable an MSI-installed per-user extension? I have the same issue.

Comment: @vizu - I found some workaround yes, it's described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/727aa30e-d3ef-439a-8bdb-b27fe33e0561/

Answer (score 3):

Use "VSIXInstaller.exe" tool from VS2010\Common7\IDE.

Also you can manually enable your extension by adding registry value to
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions