# MSI loaded extension always disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, visual-studio-extensions

I'm building a visual studio extension that needs to be installed via MSI (so that the icon type shows up in Explorer, primarily).

When I run it from the debugger in the experimental instance, everything is fine.   But when I install it in the main VS instance, the extension shows up in the list of extensions, but it's marked as `[Disabled]`.

I've verified that:

1. The directory is being created in Visual Studio\12.0\Extensions, and that it has the appropriate content.
2. The Registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\12.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions`) has an appropriate value containing the directory name;
3. The registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\12.0\ExtensionManager\ExtensionTypes` has an appropriate value containing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage`;

I've run `devenv /setup` manually before checking.

No matter what, the extension is marked as disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you say how you're currently doing the install?

Comment: I've built an MSI using the Visual Studio Installer Projects addin.

Comment: Where are you registering files? Are you doing custom actions? Do you have a build log? Without knowing the full details of what you're doing now we can't give advice.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the VS Extension Manager cannot enable or disable MSI-based extension.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393694(v=vs.100).aspx

You can try to build/deploy your MSI-based extension by using one of the methods debated in the following links and see if helps.

[How to programmatically enable visual studio extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228178/how-to-programatically-enable-visual-studio-extension)

[How can I automatically enable a VSIX extension, when installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436926/how-can-i-automatically-enable-a-vsix-extension-when-installing)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ccaa3a8-be13-4b3d-859a-0fd5d0dc7214/visual-studio-extensions-not-getting-enabled-automatically-after-installation?forum=winformssetup